# Javascript Namespace that works in IE/Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces

I am trying to create a namespace that encapsulate all our javascript classes, however am getting a *missing : after property id* in ie9 and firefox on the *POI.prototype.getFullAddress* line (the stop after the POI). The second problem is when i try to initialize the object *var x = new Makani.POI(a,b,c...)* i get javascript errors and have to use *var x = Makani.POI(a,b,c...)* without the new keyword which is weird. I posted the full code for reference. Thanks for your help.

```
/* Makani Javascript Libraries */

var Makani = function () {

var private_var;

function private_method() {

    // do stuff here

}

return {

    POI: function(ID, Title, Section, District, City, Governorate) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Section = Section;
        this.City = City;
        this.Goverorate = Governorate;
    },

    POI.prototype.getFullAddress = function (opts) {

        if (("includeCity" in opts) && (opts["includeCity"] == false))
            return this.Section + ", " + this.District;
        else if (("includeGovernorate" in opts) && (opts["includeGovernorate"] == false))
            return this.Section + ", " + this.District + ", " + this.City; 
        else return this.Section + ", " + this.District + ", " + this.City + ", " + this.Governorate;
    }

};     
} ();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [object initialiser](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.5) (*object literal*) in JS looks like this:

```
{
    propName: 123,
    123: 'some value',
    hmmAFunction: function(){}
}
```

Generally, it goes `PropertyName : AssignmentExpression` with each key/value pair separated by a comma. So, when you do this:

```
return {

    POI: function(ID, Title, Section, District, City, Governorate) {

    },

    // THIS
    POI.prototype.getFullAddress = function (opts) {

    }

};
```

... it's not valid, and will result in errors being thrown.

Try this instead:

```
var Makani = {
    POI: (function(){

        function POI (ID, Title, Section, District, City, Governorate) {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.Title = Title;
            this.Section = Section;
            this.City = City;
            this.Goverorate = Governorate;
        }

        POI.prototype.getFullAddress = function (opts) {

            if (("includeCity" in opts) && (opts["includeCity"] == false))
                return this.Section + ", " + this.District;
            else if (("includeGovernorate" in opts) && (opts["includeGovernorate"] == false))
                return this.Section + ", " + this.District + ", " + this.City; 
            else return this.Section + ", " + this.District + ", " + this.City + ", " + this.Governorate;
        };

        return POI;

    }())
};
```

Also, I advise against starting a variable name with a capital letter (e.g. `District`) unless what it references is a constructor function (like `POI`).

Comment: thanks it worked, but after reading more about the prototype object it think i wasn't using it the right way, i mean there no use in *attaching* the getFullAddress function to all instances instead of adding it to POI class directly. However, when i tried renaming POI.prototype.getFullAddress  to POI.getFullAddress i got an error when calling the getFullAddress function after initializing it, var x = new Makani.POI(...), x.getFullAddress()<- error

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just want this:

`POI.getFullAddress: function (opts) {`

It looks like you're trying to change the prototype, but you're creating an object definition in that particular block. The other way would be to create the `return` part as a var, then extend the prototype, then return it.

What you are doing at a simple level is this:

```
x = {
  name1: value,
  name2 = value
}
```

which isn't valid syntax.

Comment: See http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.5 ... You can't have a `.` in a non-quoted property name. Furthermore, we don't even want a property called `POI.getFullAdress`. For the prototype property of an object to be manipulated, that object needs to be reference'able... Hence, doing this whole thing within one object initialiser won't work. See my answer pls.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to boil it down the the basic problem: invalid syntax. The "other way" I suggested is what you did. But for the purpose of what he's trying to do here I don't see the point of adding the `getFullAddress` to the prototype, why not just add it as a member? It seems more clear, and you could never create a POI without it anyway since it's inside a function.

Comment: i was initially trying to create a simple javascript object, and then i tried to encapulate in the namespace as above, why using the prototype woulddn't be appropriate after adding it to the namespace

function POI(ID, Title, Section, District, City, Governorate) {...
and
POI.prototype.getFullAddress = function (opts) {...'